# Warning message 'indexClass<-' is deprecated from getSymbols in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I use R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) and quantmod package 0.4-15

After some recent updates, when I try to get data using quantmod:

```
getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo", from = '2010-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
```

I see the next warning message:

```
Warning message:
'indexClass<-' is deprecated.
Use 'tclass<-' instead.
```

I really can't understand what I have to change...

Comment: it would be a friendly warning for future usage

Comment: @akrun warning about what?

Comment: that instead of `indexClass` assignment, use `tclass`

Comment: As a user of the package there might be little you can do about it. The developers of the `quantmod` package will see it and if the package is under active development they might change the code to use the new function. The message appears because `quantmod` is using a function form *another* package that is  warning its users about future changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in quantmod 0.4-15, due to changes in xts 0.12-0. So you didn't do anything wrong, and you (as a user) could not have avoided it.

The bug has been fixed in quantmod 0.4-16, which is on CRAN now. That said, the Windows binaries have not been built as I write this, so you have to install from source or wait a few days.

Comment: Getting the same error with `R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)` `shiny_1.7.5.9000`, `seasonalview_0.3`, `seasonal_1.9.0` and `quantmod 0.4.25`. Any solution

Comment: @MYaseen208: this was a problem in seasonalview 0.3 and fixed in 0.4. Update to the newest seasonalview on github.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua. Updating `seasonalview` solved the problem.